# iPhone SDK - How to preload a local file in a UIWebView while starting the App?

Tags: iphone, html, sdk, uiwebview

Sorry, I couldn't find an answer to this:
My simple app has just one webview with a huge local html file (jquerymobile, many divs and images etc.). after the app has started the uiwebview needs more than 5 seconds to load and show the html file.

how can i load the html file during the app starts / shows a splash or default screen?

the goal is:
i want to make the app to show the local html file right after the default screen dissapears - or, let's say the default screen should be visible as long as the html file is loading in the background. when done, the default disapears and the uiwebview shows me the content instantly.

thanks a lot :-)

Comment: I thought it was a good pracice to have the app start as soon as possible, and then load the HTML while your UI is on the screen. This way, you can at least display an animated progress indicator.

Answer (score 0):

So I suppose you could put your UIWebView load into your `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and basically 'hold' your application in that method until you get a callback from your web view delegate (`webViewDidFinishLoad`).

I say 'suppose', because it's not particularly good design to hold the user in the start-up screen. Users will appreciate some form of visual feedback as to what's going on, particularly if it's a long load. Because the default loading screen is always a static PNG you run a large risk that after a few seconds users just 'give up' and think the app isn't going to load.

A better approach might be to consider using some kind of modal loading graphic animation. MBProgressHUD (https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) is a widely used library that provides modal loading screens with animation. You can launch it as soon as you trigger your webview load, then dismiss it when you get the loading finished callback from your webview.

Obviously neither approach is 'ideal' by Apple's guidelines (which basically are 'your app should start up extremely quickly'), but using some kind of activity indicator rather than simply holding the default screen up is going to make users much happier that the app is actually doing something, rather than simply hanging.

Answer (score 0):

For your root controller, make it implement the UIWebViewDelegate. Create a BOOL saying isLoaded. Create a method called webViewDidFinishLoad: that changes that BOOL flag to YES.  Now just add a check for that flag where appropriate.